# can ping 8.8.8.8 but not google.com

Tags: linux-mint, internet-connection

I just got a new router and internet connection. 
My phone and my second computer have no problem to connect to internet (wifi or cable). My first computer, where I am running Limux Mint 18.1 Serena, can connect with cable or wifi but I am unable to browser.
I can ping 8.8.8.8 but not google.com.

I do not understand much of DNS but I tried to follow some online tutorials.
I tried to modify the /etc/resolconf directory by adding a resolv.conf file with a new servername but didn't work (even after restarting network-manager). I tried as well to modify the /etc/resolv.conf.d/tail file (as read in other tutorials) by adding a new servername but still not working.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs due to trouble with DNS setting

If you are using linux follow:

Clear this file content (root permission required)
nano /etc/resolv.conf
Add the folling text:
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
Save and Reboot

If using Windows Follow:

Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center
Select current active connection (wifi/broadband)
Properties > Networking > ipv4 > custom dns > 1.1.1.1 & 8.8.8.8
check Validate setting upon exit > save

Comment: I tried many solutions, but only this one helped me. Issue was on Fedora 38

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS resolving doesn't work.

1. Check your firewall for an open port UDP/53 to 8.8.8.8

   `# iptables -L -n -v`
2. Check with your ISP for DNS server provided. They are probably blocking UDP/53 somewhere on the way out to force you to use internal DNS server.
   If you are on DHCP, renew the lease.
   Depends on distro (most probably networkmanager, ifdown/ifup combination may work as well). This happens quite often with resolvconfd and dnsmasq. You may need to restart the NetworkManager then
   Again - command depends on distro, usually with systemd

   `# systemctl restart NetworkManager`

If you are on static IP and have noone to ask or check their config, you may sniff `(tcpdump -nnvv -i <interface> udp port 53)`.